# Como pegar sempre os próximos 2 elementos de uma string

Tags: c#, array, for, byte

Tenho a seguinte string:
`gxAjaxKey = "FF00FFFFFFFF2426FFFFFF046448FF70"`

Devo pegar 2 elementos por vez dessa string e converter pra byte:

FF = 255

00 = 0

FF = 255

.

.

.

70 = 112

Escrevi o seguinte código :

```
int GxAjaxKeyLength = gxAjaxKey.Length;

for(int i=0; i < GxAjaxKeyLength; i += 2)
{
    var a = gxAjaxKey.Substring(i, i + 2);
    mainArray[(i/2)] = Convert.ToByte(a, 16);
}
```

O problema é que na segunda interação, em vez de pegar 00 estou pegando 00FF. Não estou enxergando onde está meu erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro de substring é a quantidade de caracteres que você quer puxar da string a partir do índice `i`. Portanto na segunda iteração do loop ele puxa de 2 até 6 `(2 + 4)`.

Para consertar você pode usar

```cs
var substring = key.Substring(i, 2);
```

Código completo:

```cs
String key = "FF00FFFFFFFF2426FFFFFF046448FF70";
int KEY_LENGTH = key.Length;

for(int i=0; i < KEY_LENGTH; i += 2)
{
  String substring = key.Substring(i, 2);
  mainArray[(i/2)] = Convert.ToByte(substring, 16);
}
```